# How do I animate elements with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

How do I say, slide an element a few pixels to the side from its initial position using jQuery? I know there is an animate() function but I have no idea how to use it. 
Tips, tutorials would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I am now trying to change the background color of an element on mouseover (I would also like to swap background images eventually, but that's not for now...)

I'm currently using the following code. what's wrong? (.link is a class referring to a bunch of a elements)

```
  //light up links on  mouseover
  $(".link").mouseover(function(event){           
    $(this).animate({'color' : '#000099'}, "fast");
  });

  //dim link on mouseout
  $(".link").mouseout(function(event){       
    $(this).animate({'color' : '#efefef'}, "fast");                
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, read the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate) for `animate`.

Then, you must define the element you are trying to move to have its `position` attribute set to `relative` or `absolute` via CSS or jQuery.

If you set it to `relative`, you can just supply the amount of pixels you want to move it with:

```
// Will move #element right 10 pixels in 500 milliseconds
$('#element').animate({
    left: 10px
}, 500);
```

If you chose absolute positioning, you must first work out the starting position of the element using `.offset().left` and add the desired amount of pixels to that, then animate to that position. For example:

```
// Will move #element right 10 pixels in 500 milliseconds
$('#element').animate({
    left: $('#element').offset().left + 10
}, 500);
```

This works if the #element's parent elements are statically positioned (otherwise the offset().left doesn't match with the absolute left value).

Comment: I think there's a better way to handle absolute positioning: $("#element").animate({left: "+=10px"}, 500); ... http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

For color animations, you need to use the [jQuery color](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) plugin.

You can use `animate()` to animate colors when you import the jQuery Color plugin.

Comment: Thanks, just curious why I cant use *animate{}*. Also, how do I use a plug-in? Do I add another script tag?

Comment: How to use a jQuery plugin is dependant on it's documentation.
Just follow the directions on the jQuery Color plugin site, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

When thinking about positional animation, you need to keep in mind that you're still just playing with the CSS.  So in your case where you want to slide over to the left a bit, you'll be wanting to adjust the left-hand margin (or potentially add padding to the right, depending on your existing styles and layout).

For example:

```
$("#myElement").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
});
```

[This site](http://blog.freelancer-id.com/index.php/2009/05/24/jquery-animate) has some useful content on basic animation and of course there is the actual [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate).

Answer (score 0):

i am really love this site , its a great recourse about jQuery

[jQuery for Designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com)